# Node.js with Socket.IO setTimeout not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, settimeout

I'm doing a little test with canvas and `Node.js`, I have this in my server.js:

```
function updateAllClients() {
    io.sockets.emit('update', {x:x, y:y});
    x++;
    y++;
    t = setTimeout(updateAllClients, 100);
}
updateAllClients();
```

And in my client:

```
socket.on('update', function(data) {
    animate(data.x, data.y);
});
```

I've checked all the functions and they are working, but the setTimeout doesn't run...

Comment: Are there any errors reported in the console?   Where are `x`, `y`, and `t` declared?  Is `io` initialized properly?  There's no enough to go on for us here without a lot more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it works for me when I put updateAllClients() inside the io.on('connection'...) function, something like that:

```
function updateAllClients() {
    io.socket.emit('update', {x:x, y:y});
    x++;
    y++;
    setTimeout(updateAllClients, 100);
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    updateAllClients();
}
```

Comment: This is really an example of how socket.io breaks everything between revisions. In a revision I tried a year ago, it was definitely not an issue to use io.blahblah inside of a globally contexted setTimeout. Socket.io team definitely know how to keep everyone on their toes